# Creating a custom control extending Image

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I have a custom control extending Image, and I will put some more data on top of that image. However, when I am trying to style the component, I am getting the error that my Custom Control do not have the property `Template` Error:

> Cannot find the Style Property 'Template' on the type 'MyCustomImage'

How can I style my custom control if Image does not have a Template Property?

Thanks

Edit:
Xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type FieldComponents:MyCustomImage}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type FieldComponents:MyCustomImage}">
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</style>
```

Comment: can you share the xaml you used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx) inherits directly from FrameworkElement, not from Control, so it does not have a Template property.  If you want to be able to template your control, you can inherit from Control or UserControl and have your template include an Image.